# simultaneously replace multiple values in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I am trying to replace values in a pandas df at the same time. It appears the function does this successively, so the values I replace end up being written over. Using below, where `X == Left`, I want to replace `A-D`, `B-C`, `C-B`, `D-A`. It works well if I only perform one of these calls but when I do all four it doesn't. Below are my attempts:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({   
    'X' : ['Left','Left','Left','Left','Right','Right','Right','Right'],
    'Y' : ['A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D'],            
    })
```

ATTEMPT1:

```
df[(df['X'] == 'Left') & (df['Y'] == 'A')] = df['Y'].map({'A': 'D'})
df[(df['X'] == 'Left') & (df['Y'] == 'B')] = df['Y'].map({'B': 'C'})
df[(df['X'] == 'Left') & (df['Y'] == 'C')] = df['Y'].map({'C': 'B'})
df[(df['X'] == 'Left') & (df['Y'] == 'D')] = df['Y'].map({'D': 'A'})
```

Out:

```
       X  Y
0      D  D
1      C  C
2      B  B
3      A  A
4  Right  A
5  Right  B
6  Right  C
7  Right  D
```

ATTEMPT 2:

```
df.loc[(df['X'] == 'Left') & (df['Y'] == 'A'), 'Y'] = 'D'
df.loc[(df['X'] == 'Left') & (df['Y'] == 'B'), 'Y'] = 'C'
df.loc[(df['X'] == 'Left') & (df['Y'] == 'C'), 'Y'] = 'B'
df.loc[(df['X'] == 'Left') & (df['Y'] == 'D'), 'Y'] = 'A'
```

Out:

```
       X  Y
0   Left  A
1   Left  B
2   Left  B
3   Left  A
4  Right  A
5  Right  B
6  Right  C
7  Right  D
```

Intended Output:

```
       X  Y
0   Left  D
1   Left  C
2   Left  B
3   Left  A
4  Right  A
5  Right  B
6  Right  C
7  Right  D
```

Comment: great example of a well written question +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do `replace` once:

```
df.Y.update(df.loc[df['X'] == 'Left','Y'].replace({'A': 'D','B': 'C','C': 'B','D': 'A'}))
df
       X  Y
0   Left  D
1   Left  C
2   Left  B
3   Left  A
4  Right  A
5  Right  B
6  Right  C
7  Right  D
```